# Reversing a list using recursion does not give the expected output

Tags: python, list, recursion

I'm looking to reverse a list using recursion in python. I succeeded in doing so but the output isn't exactly what I wanted. trying to figure out where i'm going wrong.

```
def revlist(ls):
    newlist = []
    n = len(ls)
    if n == 1:
        return ls[-1]
    else:
        return ls[-1],revlist(ls[:-1])
```

This is my output.

```
revlist([1,2,3,4])
(4, (3, (2, 1)))
```

What i'm really hoping to get is this:

```
revlist([1,2,3,4])
(4,3,2,1)
```

Comment: You're getting exactly what you asked for; your function returns either a single element or a tuple of the current last element and the rest of the iterable reversed. If you want to flatten it out, you will need to do so explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closeish.

```
def revlist(ls):
    newlist = []
    n = len(ls)
    if n == 1:
        return [ls[-1]]
    else:
        return [ls[-1]] + revlist(ls[:-1])
```

Or cleaned up:

```
def revlist(ls):
    if len(ls) < 1:
        return []
    else:
        return [ls[-1]] + revlist(ls[:-1])
```

Basically, you need to always return a `list` from your function, and append recursive calls appropriately.